# Платность программы ultraiso

Tags: ос

Хочу сделать флешку восстановления системы. Знаю, что для этого используется  ultraiso. Пошёл на [оф. сайт](https://ultraiso.ru.softonic.com/download). Там она платная. Это нормально? У меня на компе она же установлена. Сколько стоит, столько и работает, безо всякого пробного срока.

Comment: Это совершенно не официальный сайт

Comment: Хм, в Вики официальным сайтом указан этот: https://www.ezbsystems.com/ Но там тоже эта программа выставлена как платная. Это что, она действительно платная?

Comment: Ну видимо да. Поздравляю, вы пират :)

Comment: Пиастры, пьястры. Не, так а быть-то як?